# Let $T: \mathbb{R}^4 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^4$ be given by $Tv$...

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $T:\mathbb{R}^4\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^4$be given by 
$$Tv =\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 & -4 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & -5 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 
\end{pmatrix}v$$
Set $z=[1, 0 , 0 ,0]^T$. Prove that $\mathbb{R}^4 = \langle T,z\rangle $ and determine $\mu_T(x)$.

---

Let $T:\mathbb{R}^4 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^4$ be given by $Tv =[0 0 0 -4 ; 1 0 0 0 ; 0 1 0 -5 ; 0 0 1 0]$ (4x4 matrix). Set $z=[1 ; 0 ; 0 ; 0] $(4x1 matrix). Prove that $ℝ^4 = (T, z)$ and determine $μ_T (x)$. $<T, z>$

Comment: Hi AdamFox, I didn't understand what you want. I've tried to edit to improove formating, but I don't understand what you want. Can you please edit the question to make clearer what's your goal ? Thanks.

Comment: @AdamFox , I edited your answer but left the original part, as I am really not sure I edited correctly. Please check that.

Comment: Yes, thank you. That is correct

Comment: I saw, that I used $\langle T,z \rangle$. I removed that and made it to $(T,z)$ as this is what you have. Also note, that I wrote T = ... an you wrote Tv = ...

Comment: what is $\mu_T$?

Comment: <> is correct and yes that should be Tv= (matrix)*v. Where v is a vector.

Comment: But $Tz$ is a single vector and not $\mathbb{R}^4$

Comment: I would suggest that you tell us what $\mu_T(x)$ and $\langle T,z\rangle$ mean, so that we can help you.

Comment: <T,z> is the T-cyclic subspace generated by v and μ_T (x) is the order of v with respect to T.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prove that the $T$-cyclic subspace generated by $z$ is the whole $\mathbb{R}^4$, calculate $z,\,Tz,\,T^2z,\,T^3z$ and verify that they span $\mathbb{R}^4$.

As for $\mu_T(x)$, since you haven't specified what $x$ is and I am not sure what do you mean by "*the order of $v$ with respect to $T$*" in your comment, I have not any definite answer. On one hand, suppose $\mu_T(v)$ means the least positive number $k$ such that $T^kv=v$. If we abuse the notation a little bit and let $T$ denotes also its matrix representation under the standard basis, then
$$
T=P\ \underbrace{\begin{bmatrix}
0&-1\\
1&0\\
&&0&-2\\
&&2&0
\end{bmatrix}}_{D}\ P^{-1}
\quad \text{ where }
\quad P=\begin{bmatrix}
4&0&2&0\\
0&4&0&1\\
1&0&2&0\\
0&1&0&1
\end{bmatrix}.
$$
Hence $\mu_T(v)=1$ if $v=0$, $\ \mu_T(v)=4$ if $v$ is a nonzero vector of the form $v=P(x,y,0,0)^T$, and $\mu_T(x)=\infty$ otherwise.

On the other hand, if $\mu_T(v)$ means the dimension of the $T$-cyclic subspace generated by $v$, then observe that for any $v=Pu$ where $u=(x,y,z,w)^T$, we have
$$
\begin{eqnarray*}
\det(v,Tv,T^2v,T^3v)
&=\det(Pu,PDu,PD^2u,PD^3u)\\
&=\det(P)\det(u,Du,D^2u,D^3u)\\
&=\det(P)\det\begin{bmatrix}
x&  -y&  -x&   y\\
y&   x&  -y&  -x\\
z& -2w& -4z& -8w\\
w&  2z& -4w& -8z
\end{bmatrix} \\
&=\det(P)\times18(x^2+y^2)(z^2+w^2).
\end{eqnarray*}
$$
Therefore $\mu_T(v)=0$ when $v=0$, $\ \mu_T(v)=2$ when $v=P(x,y,0,0)^T\not=0$ or $v=P(0,0,z,w)^T\not=0$ and $\mu_T(v)=4$ otherwise.